# how to ensure only after service(started in alarmreceiver) finish its job the alarm should be called again

Tags: android

I have a alarm receiver start a service for every 5 mins. In the service Iam synching my database with a server. if the server splits the packets and send. I need to send the request again with a session id. The problem is when i do that i want the alarmreciever to wait until the service finish its work. ie only when i get all the packets the next 5mins should be counted. my alarm receiver:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final int PERIOD = 60000;    // 1 minute 300000 for 5 min

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,i, 0);
    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,PERIOD,pi);
}
}
```

and my Appservice

```
public class AppService extends WakefulIntentService {

public AppService() {
    super("AppService");
}

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {

    //connecting to server and getting data here.
    Log.v(null, "wake up");
            ...
            while (syncstaus.equals("more"){
            // send request again
            }


}
}
```

only after the loop finishes i want the alarm to start again. how can i do this. please throw some light on how this works

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set your alarm repeating.

Consider two options :

1) the service itself, after its job could ask the alarm manager to set a new alarm at fixed time

2) use handler.postDelayed to do that instead of alarm manager. I find more flexible.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Thanks Stephane.I will check the options. can you explain the first option. how can i start it in the service. I will go through the handler also.